# Adding an event to the checkbox in CgridView in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have added check box to each row in `cgridview`, and a button `Delete Selected` to delete the selected rows,
now what i want to do is until a check box is checked, disable the `Delete Selected` button, how do i do this.?
Here is the code of my `admin` view:

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'account-form',
        'action' => array('site/DeleteMultiple'),
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
));

 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'assign-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'selectableRows' => 2,
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'id' => 'id',
            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'username',
            'value'=>'$data->user->username',
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'Firstname',
            'value'=>'$data->user->firstname',
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
<div id="submit-button" style="display:none">
<?php 
echo CHtml::SubmitButton('Delete Selected', array('class' => 'button')); 
?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget();?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your button as below

```
echo CHtml::SubmitButton('Delete Selected', array('class' => 'button','disabled'=>'true'));
```

Then add a JS function:

```
$("#assign-grid input[type=checkbox]").click(function()
{
   if($("#assign-grid").find("input:checked").length >0)
      $(".button").removeAttr("disabled");
   else
      $(".button").attr("disabled","true");
});
```

Comment: when you click on any checkbox(line 1), 3rd line code will count the checkboxes which are all checked.

Comment: it is not working the button is being shown (disabled) but after clicking on any checkbox it is not getting enabled..what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

just try this,
create a jQuery / javascript function for show the div and call it in onclick of the check box

Like this

> array(
>               'id' => 'id',
>               'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
>               'onclick' => 'fn_onclick()'
>           ),

Comment: It is giving an error `Property "CCheckBoxColumn.onclick" is not defined. `

Comment: please try this `array( 'id' => 'id', 'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn', 'htmlOptions'=>array('onclick'=> 'fn_onclick()')),`